# PlatformIO Icon not show in my VStudio IDE

Tags: esp32, platformio

PlatformIO Icon not show in my VStudio IDE

I'm installed him but it not appears in my IDE

Someone can help me?

Thanks for help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a solution on the official platformio forums](https://community.platformio.org/t/home-icon-not-displayed/10367/2)

They managed to get it working by uninstalling all extensions and reinstalling everything. Have you tried that?